# Session increment in MVC 5

Tags: .net, session, model-view-controller, increment

We are using a session to gather products in a basket. This is just a project, and we know this isn't scalable or at all smart, it's just for show. In any case, everytime we add a product from our page, it will be added to the basket on the side through a basket. In this, we have the name, price and quantity. It adds fine as it should, but when we add the same product again it just add it to the list, not increment upon the existing product.

Is there an "easy" way to add some functionality to the existing code to do this, or is it a lost cause?

This is our controller action for adding it:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Dish dish)
        {
            Basket basket;
            if (Session["Basket"] == null)
            {
                basket = new Basket();
                Session["Basket"] = new Basket();
            }
            else
            {
                basket = (Basket)Session["Basket"];
            }
            BasketItem basketItem = new BasketItem();
            basketItem.DishId = dish.DishId; 
            basketItem.Title = dish.Title;
            basketItem.Number = dish.Number;
            basketItem.Price = dish.Price;

            basket.AddItem(basketItem);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", basket.Items);

     }
```

This is for showing it in our partial view:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult BasketItemsList()
        {


            Basket basket;

            if (Session["Basket"] == null)
            {
                basket = new Basket();
                Session["Basket"] = new Basket();
            }
            else
            {
                basket = (Basket)Session["Basket"];

            }
            return PartialView("_Basket", basket.Items);
        }
```

Comment: is BasketItem.Number supposed to be the quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `BasketItem.Number` is your quantity and `BasketItem.DishId` is your key, then just the current list by DishId and increment it if its there, or add a new one.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Dish dish)
{
    Basket basket;
    if (Session["Basket"] == null)
    {
        basket = new Basket();
        Session["Basket"] = new Basket();
    }
    else
    {
        basket = (Basket)Session["Basket"];
    }


    BasketItem basketItem = new BasketItem();
    basketItem.DishId = dish.DishId; 
    basketItem.Title = dish.Title;
    basketItem.Number = dish.Number;
    basketItem.Price = dish.Price;

    var possibleDuplicate = baskey.Items.Where(x => x.DishId == basketItem.DishId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (possibleDuplicate != null)
    {
        possibleDuplicate.Number += 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        basket.AddItem(basketItem);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", basket.Items);
 }
```

Comment: Amazing! That works, but with one except. We want the number to increment with the number selected in number. I.e: You first order 1 of a product. Then you want some more, and order 2. 

What I want, is it to increment from 1 to 3. But in the current state, it always increment by 1. Can you do 

possibleDuplicate.Number += dish.Number

?

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks for the fast answer and help.